# Как правильно типизировать объект объектов?

Tags: typescript

Пытаюсь таким способом, но выдает ошибку... Буду очень рад за помощь!

```
interface ButtonData {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  sortBy: { date: string; time?: boolean };
}

type DateButtons = { [key: ButtonData ["id"]]: ButtonData }
// error (parsing error: unexpected token, expected "]")

export const dateButtons: DateButtons  = {
  1: {
    id: '1',
    title: 'All',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD MMM YYYY', time: true },
  },
  2: {
    id: '2',
    title: '11 10 2022',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD MM YYYY' },
  },
  3: {
    id: ,
    title: '20:11 11.10.2022',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD.MM.YYYY', time: true },
  },
};
```

Comment: Нет в этом месте никакой ошибки. Давай [mcve].

Comment: У вас в 3м элементе ошибка **id: ,** Должно быть значение

Comment: вижу, но проблема не в этом